# How to fix "Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module"

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

This is the error message:

```py
> C:\Users\alex\PycharmProjects\strongkong\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\alex\PycharmProjects\strongkong\manage.py runserver 8000 
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\PycharmProjects\strongkong\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\PycharmProjects\strongkong\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 27, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

I have downloaded psycopg and psycopg2 but no result. I tried downloading psycopg-binary but again error. Please help me fix this problem.'

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module

Comment: Make sure the interpreter is set correctly - you need to install psycopg in the virtual environment that is in use for this project and has django in it, not just any python